# Spring Boot Redis error when dockerized, but not with maven run

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, redis, maven-plugin

I am building an application with Spring Boot using Redis (with redisson).

When I run my application in development mode, it works fine, but when I try to run it in docker containers, it fails with the error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.springframework.data.redis.connection.ReactiveStreamCommands
```

My maven configuration for Redis :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
             <!-- for Spring Data Redis v.2.2.x -->
             <artifactId>redisson-spring-data-22</artifactId>
             <version>3.12.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

My maven configuration to build docker container :

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <imageName>${imageName}</imageName>

                    <!-- default properties to tag an image -->
                    <image>${imageName}</image>
                    <newName>${imageName}:${tagName}</newName>

                    <!-- gitlab registry -->
                    <serverId>gitlab-repository</serverId>
                    <registryUrl>my.repository</registryUrl>

                    <baseImage>adoptopenjdk/openjdk11-openj9:latest</baseImage>
                    <entryPoint>["java", "-jar", "/${project.build.finalName}.jar"]</entryPoint>

                    <!-- copy the service's jar file from target into the root directory 
                        of the image -->
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                            <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

When I login to my container and analysie my jar libraries (with the following command):

```
jar -tf my-app.jar | grep redis
```

I find this :

```
BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-data-redis-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar
BOOT-INF/lib/spring-data-redis-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar
BOOT-INF/lib/redisson-spring-data-22-3.12.2.jar
BOOT-INF/lib/redisson-3.12.2.jar
```

Which is exactly the same as I get with my jar for development.

Here is the docker-compose extract on how I launch redis :

```
  redis:
    image: redis:5.0
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - network
    volumes:
      - redis:/data
    entrypoint: redis-server --appendonly yes 
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Any clue on what is missing for my container to run properly?
Any idea why the spring-data-redis used in the jar is 2.1.5 and not 2.2.x ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show a `Dockerfile`

Comment: Does it work if you run the jar not in docker?

Comment: Yes, it works when I run the jar from Eclipse.

Comment: I don't have a Dockerfile, only docker-compose.yml.  I added the redis part in the post

Comment: **I have found a solution :**

Instead of using `redisson-spring-data-22`, I downgraded to `redisson-spring-data-16` (as I noticed that the effective version of spring-data-redis used was in fact 2.1.5, which is lower than 2.2 ...). I cannot explain why really, but **it works now**

Answer (score 0):

**I have found a solution :**

Instead of using `redisson-spring-data-22`, I downgraded to `redisson-spring-data-16` (as I noticed that the effective version of spring-data-redis used was in fact 2.1.5, which is lower than 2.2 ...).

I cannot explain why really, but **it works now**.

I could not find any track on [redisson-spring-data](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/tree/master/redisson-spring-data) of what version should be used in what conditions, so I just tried another version ... and it worked!

Hope that helps.